# Regex - eliminate everything after nth comma

Tags: regex, pcre

I have an event source that generates much more information than needed. Most all of the events are comma separated fields.  Some events include XML information following the comma separated fields.  I want to eliminate everything after the 22nd comma to the end of the event, including all XML.   Have tried many variations of REGEX but cannot seem to get it right.

Ended up with this: `^(?:[^,\n]*,){22}((.*?))(?:.*$)`

Seems to be doing the opposite of what I want.

Comment: It's a good idea to describe your string, it's a better idea to show it.

Comment: You should capture the stuff you want to keep and discard the rest

Comment: `^((?:[^,\n]*,){22}).*$`

Comment: Did you try to use the `\K` feature that removes all before from the match result?

Comment: Are there new lines in the events after 22? `.` wont match a new line unless the `s` modifier is used. Seeing your actual usage and string would help.

Comment: The string would look similar to the following:  date,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7...... and so on to field24  following with a CR and several dozen XML lines (or SMIME?) beginning and ending with <> all broken with CR's.  In some cases a single event could be hundreds of lines long

Comment: 2016-12-06T07:55:24.623Z,1.2.3.4,server,serverIP, server.domain.com,,sourcehost,source,SMTP,SEND,1232, <24@domain.com.cn>,Yayu@partner.com,250 2.1.5 Rec OK,1002870,1,,,text,wow@domain.com,qi.wang@domain.com,2016164,Incoming,,,,SE2ELatency
    <Meeting Subject="StartTime="12/02/2016 15:00:00" EndTime="12/02/2016 16:00:00" Organizer="prime@domain.com">
      <InternetMessageId>&</InternetMessageId>
      <GlobalObjectId>0131324E00</GlobalObjectId>
      <CleanGlobalObjectId>00E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000eanGlobalObjectId>
      <OwnerAppointmentId>-1</OwnerAppointmentId>
      <Attendees>

Comment: How are commas escaped in the first 22 fields?

Comment: I currently use "s/<Meeting([\s\S]*)/ /g" which starts at "<Meeting".   I need to start much further in.  The sample data above is much shorter than original.  I am trying to use "s/^((?:[^,\n]*,){22}).*$/ /g" buy is eliminating everything before the 22nd comma, not after.

Comment: Made "some" progress.  Using $1 replaces the first capture group, so now have "s/^((?:[^,]*,){22}).*/$1/g".  This captures everything in the message line and replaces it with the everything up to the 22nd comma.  Problem is, everything past <Meeting is treated as new content/new lines (assuming) and therefore is not replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.....   s/((?:[^,]*,){22}).*((\s+\S+).*){1,}/$1/g

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, this might do a better job:

```
s/^([^,]*+(?:,[^,]*+){0,21}).*?$/$1/gsm
```